# PHP MySQL follower system like twitter

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a user follower system and I need a little help with it. What I want to do is if `user 1` is logged in and following `user 2`, system should show that `user 1` is following `user 2` from a list of users.

Followers are displaying fine. What I want is to display if the logged in user following another user is show the text `following` and if not show text `follow`. How do I do that?

**User table**

```
----------------------
uid  | username
----------------------
```

**Follow table**

```
------------------------------------------
fid  | follower_id | followed_id
------------------------------------------
```

**My query for getting followers**

```sql
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    followers
        LEFT JOIN
    users ON users.uid = followers.follower_id
WHERE
    followers.followed_id = '$my_id'
```

**Logged in user**

```php
if(isset($_SESSION['myuser'])){
    $user_id = some_id;
}
```

I can run another query inside the 1st query but i'm trying to do it with one query.

Comment: You filter on the follower_id in the where criteria instead of the followed_id.

Comment: You need to do something like - retrieve all `fid`'s (users being followed by logged in user) and compare with all `uid`'s. If `fid` is present in `uid`: **Following** else **Follow**. How you compare it depends on frontend you are using.

Answer (score 0):

On the `WHERE` clause, filter according to `follower_id` field, not `followed_id`.

```
SELECT *
FROM followers
LEFT JOIN users ON users.uid = followers.follower_id
WHERE followers.follower_id = '$my_id'
```